# AWS Lambda boto3 from management console "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'",

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am writing a lambda in python boto3 directly on AWS Management console. I need to import a module called requests. But when I run the lambda, I get the following error. At my employer I can't download the requests moduel and zip it and upload with the code.

Response
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"requestId": "9b50cc12-1971-4bb5-a512-316e8ec380da",
"stackTrace": []
}

```
 import json
 import time
 import boto3
 import traceback
 import os
 import base64
 import logging
 import tempfile
 import uuid
 import requests     
 
 def lambda_handler(event, context):

   print("hello")
```